# Sleep function for React-Native?

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, reactjs, react-native

So I'm trying to fetch all 'places' given some location in React Native via the Google Places API. The problem is that after making the first call to the API, Google only returns 20 entries, and then returns a `next_page_token`, to be appended to the same API call `url`. So, I make another request to get the next 20 locations right after, but there is a small delay (1-3 seconds) until the token actually becomes valid, so my request errors.

I tried doing:

```
this.setTimeout(() => {this.setState({timePassed: true})}, 3000);
```

But it's completely ignored by the app...any suggestions?

**Update**

I do this in my `componentWillMount` function (after defining the variables of course), and call the `setTimeout` right after this line.

```
axios.get(baseUrl)
.then((response) => {
   this.setState({places: response.data.results, nextPageToken: response.data.next_page_token });

});
```

Comment: Can you show some more of your code?

Comment: Where are you calling setTimeout() ?

Comment: @Chase updated the question, sorry bout that.

Comment: @LukeCage can you show how you're using the `timePassed` variable in the second request? Right off the bat I can tell you that you should probably start your timeout within the .then function since it is asynchronous and you don't know how much time has elapsed between mounting, requesting and response.

Comment: Also you can should just call `setTimeout` and not `this.setTimeout`

Comment: @Chase yea I tried doing it that way as well, I'm not using the `timePassed` variable in the second request, I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @LukeCage What I mean is you're performing a second request after three seconds to get more data right? This obviously can't happen in componentWillMount since the component has already mounted before the response is even returned. I'm just curious how your getting the next set of data.

Comment: @Chase I wasn't aware that it would mount before the `setTimeout` function was executed...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131108/discussion-between-chase-and-lukecage).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What I understood is that you are trying to make a fetch based on the result of another fetch. So, your solution is to use a TimeOut to guess when the request will finish and then do another request, right ?

If yes, maybe this isn't the best solution to your problem. But the following code is how I do to use timeouts:

```
// Without "this"
setTimeout(someMethod,
    2000
)
```

The approach I would take is to wait until the fetch finishes, then I would use the callback to the same fetch again with different parameters, in your case, the `nextPageToken`. I do this using the ES7 async & await syntax.

```
// Remember to add some stop condition on this recursive method.
async fetchData(nextPageToken){
    try {
        var result = await fetch(URL)
        // Do whatever you want with this result, including getting the next token or updating the UI (via setting the State)
        fetchData(result.nextPageToken)
    } catch(e){
         // Show an error message
    }
}
```

If I misunderstood something or you have any questions, feel free to ask!

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

try this it worked for me:

```
  async componentDidMount() {
     const data = await this.performTimeConsumingTask();

        if (data !== null) {
       // alert('Moved to next Screen here');
    this.props.navigator.push({
        screen:"Project1.AuthScreen"})
        }
  }
  performTimeConsumingTask = async() => {
    return new Promise((resolve) =>
      setTimeout(
        () => { resolve('result') },
        3000
      )
    );
  }
```